# Bash script with filenames with spaces / chown mirroring

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file structure that became corrupted due to ownership change by a faulty software. I have an almost identical structure which was from a previous backup.

What I'm trying to accomplish is mirror file ownership as possible, to fix this issue.

I've got the following script, but it fails due to spaces on filenames/dirs:

```
IFS=$'\n'
D1=/Users/emarques/temp/test\ 1
D2=/Users/emarques/temp/test\ 2
for entry in $(find $D1  -exec stat -f "%N:%u:%g" {} \;); do 
    $(echo \"$entry\" | \
        tr -d '"' | \
        sed 's#'$D1'#'$D2'#' | \
        awk -F: '{printf ("chown %s %s\n", $2 ":" $3, "\"" $1 "\"")}')
done
```

**Output**

```
-bash: chown 0:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/1": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/1/a": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/1/b": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/2": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/2/a": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 502:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/2/b": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/3": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 502:80 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/a": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 502:80 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/b": No such file or directory
-bash: chown 501:20 "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/c": No such file or directory
```

I request help from IT colleagues, as I haven't figured out how to make this work yet. Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: `No such file or directory`. Can you show an output of an `ls` on `temp` directory.

Comment: Have you confirmed *variable expansion* actually takes place in `sed 's#'$D1'#'$D2'#'`?

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is quite pertinent. Keep in mind that when you set `IFS=$'\n'`, you're preventing the space between `chown` and its arguments from triggering string-splitting.

Comment: Thank you all that gave your input. You helped me a lot! Particularly Muru and Ghoti for their extensive and correct approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some versions of `chown` support a "reference file" option:

```
--reference=RFILE
      use  RFILE's  owner and group rather than specifying OWNER:GROUP
      values
```

If your `chown` does, then do:

```
cd "/Users/emarques/temp/test 1"
find . -exec sh -c 'chown --reference="$1" "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/$1"' _ {}
```

Or, slightly more complex, but probably more efficient:

```
cd "/Users/emarques/temp/test 1"
find . -exec sh -c 'for f; do chown --reference="$f" "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/$f"; done' _ {} +
```

You'll have to worry less about quoting.

If your `chown` doesn't support reference files, then:

```
cd "/Users/emarques/temp/test 1"
shopt -s globstar dotglob
for f in **/*
do
    chown "$(stat -f "%u:%g" "$f")" "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/$f"
done
```

By starting out from inside the first directory, you can save yourself a lot of hassle since you get the relative path for free.

Comment: It'd be considerably more efficient, and still entirely POSIX-compliant (except for `--reference`, of course), to use `-exec sh -c 'for arg; do chown --reference="$arg" "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/$arg"; done' _ {} +` -- that way you're not spinning up a copy of `/bin/sh` for each and every file found.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I considered that, but since we're going to spin up a copy of chmod for each file anyway, I felt that the added verbosity doesn't really help.

Comment: We're talking very nearly twice the `fork()` and `exec()` calls, here... and if your `/bin/sh` is actually busybox, then it can run chmod as a builtin.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was to keep it actually simpler than what I was doing. Starting out inside the first directory is a better way to do it. This worked out: `for f in *; do chown "$(stat -f "%u:%g" "$f")" "/Users/emarques/temp/test 2/$f"; done`

Answer (score 2):

From the options on your `stat` command and the structure of your user directories, I suspect you're running this in macOS, which means you may be limited to bash v3, and your tools (like stat and chown) use BSD options.

Just at first glance, here are some things you shouldn't do.

- You need to quote the rest of your variables. You include a space in `$D1`, but then you `find $D1` instead of `find "$D1"`. Note that `echo \"$entry\"` contains an unquoted variable. Where you *need* to quote variables is anywhere they might be split by whitespace. Since that's sometimes hard to know, just quote them everywhere.
- When you `for entry in $(find ...)` and the results of that `find` include spaces, you are unlikely to get the results you are looking for. For an explanation as to why, check out the [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) page. (You're trying to mitigate this by setting `$IFS`, but that complicates other things.)

Instead of this, you can use one of a number of approaches.

**1 - Run everything in `find`.**

You already know about the `find` command's `-exec` option. You can load more into `find`. The following is untested:

```
cd "$D1"
find . -exec sh -c 'chown $(stat -f "%u:%g" {}) $0/{}' "$D2" \;
```

**2 - Use a better delimiter.**

The `find` command has a `-print0` option, which causes files to be separated by nulls instead of whitespace. This is also untested:

```
find "$D1" -print0 | while read -d$'\0' file; do
  chown $(stat -f '%u:%g' "$file") "$D2/$file"
done

done
```

**3 - Avoid find, use globstar if you can.**

This only works if you have bash 4 available, since bash 3 (the default in macOS) doesn't include globstar. (You can install bash 4 using [macports](http://macports.org) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) if you want.)

```
D1="/Users/emarques/temp/test 1"
D2="/Users/emarques/temp/test 2"

shopt -s globstar

# If there are files in D2 that might not appear in D1...
cd "$D1"
for file in **; do
  chown $(stat -f '%u:%g' "$file") "$D2/$file"
done

# Or if there are files in D1 which might be missing from D2...
cd "$D2"
for file in **; do
  chown $(stat -f '%u:%g' "$D1/$file") "$file"
done
```

Two starting points are here in case the file lists don't match exactly. If they do match, the two options should be equivalent.

Comment: `-d$'\0' file` is literally exactly the same as `-d file`. This is part of why I consider `-d $'\0' file` (which at least works) near-criminally bad practice as opposed to `-d '' file`: The former leads folks to believe, incorrectly, that `$'\0'` actually has meaning to the shell (which it doesn't, and can't, in any shell using NUL-delimited strings), whereas grokking the latter forces understanding of (necessary and important!) implementation details (particularly, that arguments are *all* internally represented as C strings).

Comment: (err, that `$'\0'` has meaning *distinct from* `''`, that is)

Comment: Thank ghoti! Your answer was very helpful! You and Muru were right. I'm marking his answer as right because he was first to answer.